# Updating values of array - PHP

Tags: php

I have a shopping cart. I add items to them and this is the code of inserting an item to the cart.

My problem is that for some reason, when I have more than one element in my cart, If I add more quantity to one item, the quantity will be updated on the item with index + 1.

For example.
Empty cart now.
Add item A, 1 quantity.
Cart = item A , 1 quantity
Add item B, 1 quantity.
Cart = item A , 1 quantity, item B 1 quantity.
But now comes the problem.
If i add item A 1 quantity again. My cart will be
Cart = item A, 1 quantity, item B 2 quantity....

Can someone help me ?

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once("dbcontroller.php");
$db_handle = new DBController();
        if(!empty($_POST["quantity"])) {
            $productByCode = $db_handle->runQuery("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id='" . $_GET["id"] . "'");
            $itemArray = array($productByCode[0]["id"]=>array('name'=>$productByCode[0]["name"], 'id'=>$productByCode[0]["id"], 'quantity'=>$_POST["quantity"], 'price'=>$productByCode[0]["price"], 'image'=>$productByCode[0]["image"]));

            if(!empty($_SESSION["cart_item"])) {
                if(in_array($productByCode[0]["id"],array_keys($_SESSION["cart_item"]))) {
                    foreach($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $k => $v) {
                            if($productByCode[0]["id"] == $k) {

                                if(empty($_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]["quantity"])) {
                                    $_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]["quantity"] = 0;
                                }
                                $_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]["quantity"] += $_POST["quantity"];

                            }
                    }
                } else {
                    $_SESSION["cart_item"] = array_merge($_SESSION["cart_item"],$itemArray);
                }
            } else {
                $_SESSION["cart_item"] = $itemArray;
            }
        }


?>
```

And this is the code I use to output HTML.

```
$template->setCurrentBlock("SHOPPINGCART");

foreach ($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $item){
    $item_price = $item["quantity"]*$item["price"];
    $template->setVariable("item_image", $item['image']);
      $template->setVariable("item_name", $item['name']);
      $template->setVariable("item_id", $item['id']);
      $template->setVariable("item_quantity", $item['quantity']);
      $template->setVariable("item_price", $item['price']);
      $template->parseCurrentBlock();
    }
```

Comment: Is the problem in database cart or session cart only?

Comment: only session cart.

Comment: Try this `$_SESSION["cart_item"][$k - 1]["quantity"] += $_POST["quantity"];` or `if($productByCode[$k]["id"] == $k)` Don't Know which part of code does what. I should leave comments in code

Comment: @SilvioCro, I tried and didnt work. Thanks neverthless.

Comment: The whole handling of the cart array data is rather bogus and convoluted. You don’t have to test whether `$_SESSION["cart_item"]` is empty. All those in_array calls and looping over all the data to find a specific item, also unnecessary. `$_SESSION["cart_item"][some-product-id]` is either set or not. If not, add an entry, using `$_SESSION["cart_item"][some-product-id] = […]`, otherwise add to the existing quantity value, `$_SESSION["cart_item"][some-product-id]["quantity"] += ...`

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand your code but to be sure you are getting the product details and putting it to the cart session correct me if I'm wrong.

```
if(isset($_POST['quantity'])){

    $qty  = $_POST['quantity'];

    $pid = $_POST['id'];

    //retrieve product as object
    $result = json_encode($db_handle->runQuery("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id='" . $_GET["id"] . "'"));

    //decode the object
    $item = json_decode($result);

    //assign product id as key and the item collection as value 
    $_SESSION['cart_item'][$pid] = $item;
    //then you have to assign the quantity 
    $_SESSION['cart_item'][$pid]->quantity = $qty;

    //You can check now that quantity is updating accordingly and you have access to all props of your product
    var_dump($_SESSION['cart_item']);

    echo $_SESSION['cart_item'][$pid]->quantity;

}
```

I hope this helps!